# QB64: Run it w/o the Terminal?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I've successfully installed and run the QB64 IDE on Ubuntu **18.04** LTS, but I still need to drag the script file **run_qb64.sh** into the terminal to make it run.  There has to be a way to do it **w/o** the terminal....right?  Thanks.
https://www.qb64.org/

Comment: Long story short: make a `.desktop` file as explained in the linked duplicate. They are similar to Windows shortcuts essentially.